# Edit js file after it's loaded

Tags: javascript

I have a fix that I need to apply on some js files that I'm not owner of. I thought of adding some javascript content to the loaded javascript (loaded dynamically) file before it starts executing the content. I know it's a long shot, but, is it even possible?

Comment: You can override functions or variables on your side existing script, you may try this as solution, if you give a concrete situation it will be more helpful

Comment: so my problem is that i need to add this code _document.body.appendChild(document.body.querySelectorAll('script[title="my-component"')[0]);_ in the beginning of the file, it won't make sense to you but it is a workaround to a bug that is not yet fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the solution, and, instead of loading the script using: `<script src="/my/script/path"></script>`  I loaded it using the XMLHttpRequest like this

```
var client = new XMLHttpRequest();
client.open('GET', widget.link);
client.onreadystatechange = this.applyStencilFix;
client.send();
```

and then I applied my fix editing the the script as a text

```
applyFix(e: Event): void {
  let request: any = e.target;
  if(request.responseText) {
    let script = document.createElement('script');
    script.text = "myFix" + request.responseText;
    script.title = request.responseURL;
    document.body.appendChild(script);
  }
}
```

and, voilà :)

Answer (score 0):

Just let the external JavaScript load and then operate on whichever elements you need to, like this:

```
 window.onload=function(){ModifyElements();};
```

And then further down...

```
    function ModifyElements(){

     // How are we going to recognise those elements so as to operate on them?

     // Do you know the ID ?

     Abc.style.width='20px';


     // Do you know their class?

     var N=document.querySelectorAll('.Comets'); 

     for(var i=0; i<N.length; i++){Comets[i].style.color='red';}

     // Some other way???

 }
```

Comment: not really what I'm looking for, please check my comment above.

Comment: You obviously need to add more specific info.

Comment: perhaps you could point out what it needs to be clarified more.

Comment: Are you trying to duplicate an element? You're missing a square bracket in there btw...

Comment: well, I have a script tag that is placed in the body and I want it to be placed at the end of the body just before the file that I loaded starts executing its script, I hope that helps, by the way appendChild create an element if it doesn't exist, if it does it move it.

Comment: Are you looking for this? document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend','<script></script>');

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190850/discussion-between-malek-yahyaoui-and-user4723924).